# Setup Moq To Return Multiple Values

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am new to Moq and I want to have a test like this:

```
[Fact]
        public void IsClientExternalForWebShouldReturnFalse()
        {
            // Arrange
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            request.Setup(r => r.UserHostAddress).Returns(new Queue<string>(new[] { "127.0.0.1", "10.1.10.1" }).Dequeue);

            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

            var service = new EnvironmentService(context.Object, null);

            // Act / Assert
            service.IsClientExternal.Should().BeFalse();
            service.IsClientExternal.Should().BeFalse();
        }
```

It throws this:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: SAIF.Services.Tests.dll ------

Test 'SAIF.Services.Tests.EnvironmentServiceTests.IsClientExternalForWebShouldReturnFalse' failed: System.InvalidOperationException : Queue empty.
    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1.Dequeue()   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1.Dequeue()   at Moq.Extensions.InvokePreserveStack(Delegate del, Object[] args)
    at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2.Execute(ICallContext call)
    at Moq.Interceptor.Intercept(ICallContext invocation)
    at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.Interceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
    at Castle.Proxies.HttpRequestBaseProxy.get_UserHostAddress()
    Services\EnvironmentService.cs(54,0): at SAIF.Services.EnvironmentService.<get_IsClientExternal>b__3(String ip)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
    Services\EnvironmentService.cs(54,0): at SAIF.Services.EnvironmentService.get_IsClientExternal()
    EnvironmentServiceTests.cs(25,0): at SAIF.Services.Tests.EnvironmentServiceTests.IsClientExternalForWebShouldReturnFalse()

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 0.69 seconds (xUnit.net 1.9.1 build 1600).
```

The actual code under test:

```
public bool IsClientExternal
        {
            get { return IsWeb && !internalAddressRoots.Any(ip => httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress.StartsWith(ip)); }
        }
```

But if I only call to the service once it works, but the service only gets the first value.

Also if I debug and mouse over the `httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress`, the value changes.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1**

So I found the issue I think. This issue is that the actual code under test loops through all the ip's and doing that calls the `UserHostAddress`. I just really need to figure out how to supply an array of strings into the `Returns()` function of the mock.

Comment: Why do you need to test it few times?

Comment: @Bartosz - I need to make sure a given number of IP's are tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserHostAddress` property might be called few times in call to `Any`, and we do not know how many times it's gonna be called (depends on content of `internalAddressRoots`). So by the time you get to the second service call, your queue might be empty.

If you really want to test twice, maybe you should setup twice. Subsequent setups override previous ones:

```
    public void IsClientExternalForWebShouldReturnFalse()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        request.Setup(r => r.UserHostAddress).Returns("127.0.0.1");

        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

        var service = new EnvironmentService(context.Object, null);

        // Act / Assert
        service.IsClientExternal.Should().BeFalse();

        request.Setup(r => r.UserHostAddress).Returns("10.1.10.1");
        service.IsClientExternal.Should().BeFalse();
    }
```

As you see, we're mixing setup with the assert part, which doesn't look that good, but I'm not sure about your motives, so here's one possible solution.

Comment: Exactly! I figured that out shortly after. Any ideas? Do you think a for loop in the test to test for each IP is OK? I know you are only supposed to `Assure` once, but really this is one condition under test.

Comment: Updated the answer with solution to use multiple setups on same property. Not really good one, but I'm still unsure why do you need to do this twice.

Comment: Basically I need to have this test run for multiple ip's. Should I have separate tests? What about SetupSequence?

Comment: I would just have two seperate tests and derive them from a common context base class.